# ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> numa Classe BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

Eu tenho o seguinte Arraylist:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItens = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hashMap.put("chave_" + i, "valor_" + i);
}
menuItens.add(hashMap);
```

Agora, na Classe que extende a BaseAdapter eu pretendo capturar do `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` os dois valores "chave" e "valor" para aplicar numa ListView.

Qual a melhor forma de capturar estes dois valores (chave e valor) a fim de os adicionar em duas Strings?

Comment: Cara, dando uma rápida olhada no seu código, eu não entendi duas coisas. A primeira é, você realmente precisa de um `ArrayList`? Não basta um `HasMap`, já que ele suporta mais de um elemento dentro dele. A segunda é se esse código está rodando corretamente, já que você adiciona o elemento apenas depois do `for`, o que adicionaria apenas um elemento no `ArrayList`...

Comment: Olá Filipe! Eu necessito de um ArrayList porque cada Objeto HasMap vai possuir valores diferentes. Enquanto aguardava por ajuda, descrobri na internet a seguinte forma de capturar os valores do HasMap no ArrayList e que resolveu o meu problema: <code>String str1 = arrayList.get(position).get("chave_" + position)</code>